# In R, what are my options for automatic package updates?

Tags: r, git, version-control, package, toolchain

I have a number of custom-built R packages hosted on a private Git server. These packages are still being developed, so their contents change frequently.

Currently, developers using the packages lose substantial time when the packages are updated. Their workflow is:

For each package:

1. `git pull` the repo
2. Open the package in RStudio
3. Run `devtools::document()`
4. Run "Build & Reload"

With several packages this can take a good 15 minutes.

What are the best alternatives to this?

Comment: I'm sure you tried that already, but I'm curious anyway, have you tried `devtools::install_git`?

Comment: That crashes my R session when I call it for a private git instance.